# Notepad++ like highlighting in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

In Notepad++ if I highlight a word other instances of that word in the document will also be highlighted. This is independent of, and in addition to, the actual search/find functionality.

Chrome has similar functionality when using the find in page (ctrl-f) function. But is there any way to enable (or plugin that provides) this highlighting psuedo search behavior?

Comment: But did you search via ctrl-f, or did you highlight one instance of the word Chrome, and then the other instances were highlighted as well?

Comment: Right. I already mentioned that that was possible. It's not the functionality I'm looking for.

Comment: Yes, but they both have the ability to search for and highlight text. The fact that one is primarily intended for text editing vs text consumption doesn't preclude them from sharing common functionality.

Comment: I don't know of a solution in Chrome.  However, I would start the question with "I want Chrome to automatically highlight all examples of a text snippet when I select one, like in Notepad++."

Answer (score 0):

The Chrome extension "Highlight all on dblclick" provides this functionality. It will also allow for multiple highlight searches, each in a different color.